# Is there a way to build AWS S3 bucket endpoints automatically, regardless of region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I have an app in Node that accesses stuff in buckets.  I want it to be able to use buckets in any region, transparently. Unfortunately, the way of building the URL for the endpoint differs based on what region you're in.

If it's in US-Standard, I can say http://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/path/to/file. If it's anywhere else, that doesn't work (non-coincidentally, you're limited to domain-allowed characters (lowercase and numbers only) for bucket names in non-US Standard) and you use http://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.

(Note you can get more complicated and say

I'm thinking this is not a unique problem, so want to put it out there.

Answer (score 1):

http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file works in US-Standard also, so you should be able to use this single construct on any bucket anywhere (unless I'm missing something in your question).

Comment: OK, I'm definitely confused.  My initial research indicated that US Standard buckets names have a much larger character set (can have upper and lower case letters).  So for example, AAbbCC is a legal name in US Standard and is a different bucket from AABBCC.  Thus it's not suitable to use in the http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file format.  (because domain names are not case sensitive).  Of course, pathnames can be case sensitive.  Can you confirm/deny/state unequivocally?

Comment: You're right -- they "have" an expanded character set, but *using* those additional characters is a really bad idea... lowercase dns-compatible bucket names is the best and least-potentially-problematic practice.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html last sentence.

Comment: You are, of course, correct that buckets with incompatible names can'r be addressed this way.  This fact will break some S3 libraries and tools because they assume all buckets work via this mechanism.